# Is offering 2 Apps at the same time a bad experience for the User?

Tags: user-expectation, web-app, mobile-application

So we have our Website as a [PWA (Progressive Web App)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_applications) which means it can also be installed as a App on the Device from the Browser.

I wondered how it would feel for the User to have Downloaded the PWA from the Website only to realize that there is a App in the Playstore that does nearly the same thing with just some extended features (example Reddit App).

Is there any way to handle this on a smooth way without confusing the User?

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the app has some extended functionality - there's something to hang your product positioning onto.

You could also refer to the browser PWA the 'web-based' version of your product.

There are quite a few services that do this - off the top of my head, I'm thinking Evernote, Hemingway, Google Docs, Sheets, etc. All accessible online or downloadable apps.

One option could be, when accessing either version, to offer direction to the other version, with some microcopy highlighting the difference - i.e. 'Want to use ReallyGreatPWA offline? Download from Google Play' or 'Want to sync across devices? Access ReallyGreatPWA on the web, from anywhere'

Comment: The thing is a PWA is like a App on the Device Home Screen, also offline usable thats why im asking

Comment: Then I'd still say it's about positioning. Think about the motivations a user might have for using your PWA vs. using the app, then use those to position the offer.